# Laravel How to put data horizontally into Three columns with foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel-dompdf to create PDF file. I want to use foreach loop  to put data horizontally into three columns. It is not easy.

$items = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'ffff', 'gggg', 'hhhh', 'iiii'];

[image]

```
<table style="width:100%">

@foreach($items as $key => $item)

  <tr>

  @if($key % 2 == 0)<td>{{ $item }}</td>@endif

  @if($key % 2 != 0)<td>{{ $item }}</td>@endif


  </tr>

@endforeach

</table>
```

Comment: Update your question with output of `dd($couponcodes)`

Comment: it is just an array. i will update.

Comment: what is wrong with your code? where is the problem?

Comment: it is not working correctly as I would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
@foreach($data as $key => $item)

    @if ($key % 3 == 0)
        <tr>
    @endif

    <td>{{ $item }}</td>

    @if (($key + 1) % 3 == 0)
        </tr>
    @endif

@endforeach

@if (($key + 1) % 3 != 0)
    </tr>
@endif
```

You have to:

- Start with a `<tr>` tag (or every 3 records)
- Close `<tr>` tag when you processed 3 records
- After the loop you must check if the last `<tr>` tag has been closed, otherwise close it

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet,

```
<table style="width:100%">
    @foreach($items as $key => $item)
        @if($key % 3 == 0) <!-- if index % 3 is 0 then create tr -->
        <tr>
        @endif
            <td>{{$item}}</td>
        @if(($key+1) % 3 == 0) <!-- if index + 1 % 3 is 0 then close tr -->
        </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    @if(count($items) % 3 != 0)
        </tr>
    @endif
</table>
```

Comment: you are forgetting to close tr tag after the foreach if the last condition is false

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    @foreach($items as $key => $item)
        @if($i == 2)
        <tr>
        @endif
            <td>{{$item}}</td>
        @if($i == 2)
            <?php $i = 0; ?> 
        </tr>
        @endif
       <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
</table>
```